# Не монтируется файловая система aufs

Tags: ubuntu, файловая-система

Собираю сборку с оригинальным ядром. Меняю ядро на машине — работает, а в сборке — пишет ошибку:

> mounting aufs on /root failed: No such device aufs mount failed

Собираю через remastersys.

Как исправить? В группе ubuntu подсказали, что где-то в `/etc/fstab/`.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый, это у тебя сперва ядро было под aufs заточено, а в стандартном-то нету! Это тебе, дорогой, либо в ядро своё поддержку aufs вкомпиливать, либо модули для этой ФС делать! Нестандарная она, дорогой!

ЗЫ: Поддержка aufs есть в современных Knoppix и Xandros.